# Mongodb calcul consumption between data

Tags: mongodb, automation, calculation

Supposing i have this kind of collection :

```
{
    id : 1,
    date : 2018-01-31 00:00:00
    value : 1532
},
{
    id : 1,
    date : 2018-01-31 01:00:00
    value : 1542
},
{
    id : 1,
    date : 2018-01-31 10:37:00
    value : 1563
},
{
    id : 1,
    date : 2018-01-31 06:00:00
    value : 1680
}
```

I have to create an incremental mapreduce to make another collection store consumption beetween data as they arrive, so basically, my other collections must have these kind of data :

```
{
    id : 1,
    date : 2018-01-31 01:00:00
    value : 10 // 1542-1532
},
{
    id : 1,
    date : 2018-01-31 10:37:00
    value : 21 // 1563-1542
},
{
    id : 1,
    date : 2018-01-31 06:00:00
    value : 117 // 1680-1563
}
```

So is map reduce the best solution to perform this, and how can i reduce all my data ?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: @AlexBlex i tried with mapReduce, but i don't really know if this was a good idea with MongoDB

Comment: Calculate it on mongodb side is not good idea at the first place. It is a document-oriented database, which means it works best with individual documents. If you can do it on application layer, it will be way more efficient.  Otherwise show best of your attempts with map-reduce or try aggregation.

Comment: @AlexBlex interesting. So aggregation and node.js recording is better option ? using mickl's solution

Comment: no, aggregation is not much better than map-reduce. it still does the job on db side and squares dataset internally. Apart from that, your `2018-01-31 10:37:00 - 1563` somehow comes before `2018-01-31 06:00:00 - 1680`. If you rely on date field instead of insertion order to build the sequence, you need to add `$sort` as the first stage in mickl's answer.

Comment: Okay, I take my words back. You still can do it with aggregation relatively cheap if you use v3.4+. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with aggregation framework combining [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and [$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) to calculate difference between consecutive documents as following:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $sort: { date: 1 } }, // only if you want records in chronological order based on date field instead of _id
    { $group: {
        _id: "$id",
        data: { $push: { date: "$date", value: "$value" } }
    } },
    { $addFields: { shift: { $slice: [ "$data", 1, { $size: "$data" } ] } } },
    { $project: {
        diff: {
            $zip: { inputs: [ "$data", "$shift" ] }
        }
    } },
    { $unwind: "$diff" },
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        id: "$_id",
        date: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    base: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$diff", 1 ] }
                },
                in: { $add: [ "$$base.date", 0 ] }
            }
        },
        value: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    base: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$diff", 1 ] },
                    prev: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$diff", 0 ] }
                },
                in: { $subtract: [ "$$base.value", "$$prev.value" ] }
            }
        }
    } }
];
```

It still doubles the dataset internally, which is okay when you retrieve data for all `id`'s. If you need diffs for a single `id`, the best option is to do plain [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) and calculate diffs clientside:

```
let prev;
db.col.find({ id: 1 }).map( doc => { 
    if (!prev) {
        prev = doc;
        return null;
    }
    const res = {date: doc.date, value: doc.value - prev.value};
    prev = doc;
    return res;
} ).slice(1);
```

Iterating the cursor as data arrives has the minimal impact on performance. Please refer to documentation of your client library how to stream data.